# Use PostGIS geography point with hibernate spatial 5 in spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, postgis

Apparently with Hibernate 5, the geography type is supported. I've searched a lot, but found close to nothing related to the geography points.

What I want to do is the following:

1. Save Long/Lat Points in the database table, e.g. `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(6.463471 52.484832)', 4326)`
2. Perform queues to check if the Point is in a Long/Lat rectangle like :

   `WHERE  point && ST_MakeEnvelope (5.440433, 39.480434, 8.464680, 55.486190, 4326)`

I'm using **PostgreSQL** and **PostGIS**.

I just cannot find which type of column annotation for hibernate I have to use to get Long/Lat Points, and also how to perform above query.

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
```

Is not a point regarding Long/Lat

Is there any documentation regarding this (note: not geometry points).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using hibernate version 5.4.30

Regarding your question 1,
You don't want to use any type of annotations to mark the field as Point type. Specifying the datatype as Point in your entity model is enough

```
@Entity
public class UserLocation {

    //other fields   
    private Point location;
    
    //constructors, getters & setters
```

Just make sure, you import Point from

> import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;

To convert Latitude and longitude to Point, I use a Utility function

```
public class GeometryUtil {
    
    public static final int SRID = 4326; //LatLng
    private static WKTReader wktReader = new WKTReader();
    
    private static Geometry wktToGeometry(String wellKnownText) {
        Geometry geometry = null;
        
        try {
            geometry = wktReader.read(wellKnownText);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("###geometry :"+geometry);
        return geometry;
    }
     public static Point parseLocation(double x,double y) {
        Geometry geometry = GeometryUtil.wktToGeometry(String.format("POINT (%s %s)",x,y));
         Point p =(Point)geometry;
         p.setSRID(4326); 
         return p;
     }
}
```

To create a point from latitude and longitude using

**MySQL**

> Point p = GeometryUtil.parseLocation(latitude,longitude);

**PostGIS**

> Point p = GeometryUtil.parseLocation(longitude,latitude);

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day. Yet, it should be reversed, double lng and double lat in parseLocation signature, otherwise it gets a bit messy when you use it.

Comment: Thanks, @woland, I'm very glad that my answer has helped you, I've written the code for MySQL. I have also added the code for PostGIS, could you please check it for me?

Answer (score 1):

Type will remain GeometryType just use distance in decimal and by below mention code you can get all location within 50 to 110 meters as i use 0.001, you can use according to your requirements.

```
GeometryFactory factory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326);
        factory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude,latitude));
        Point comparisonPoint = factory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude,latitude));
        predicates.add(SpatialPredicates.distanceWithin(cb, geom from db), comparisonPoint, 0.001));
```

distanceWithin() function take distance in degree which you have to cast to geograph but hibernate Spatial doesn't support so there is another way by which you can achieve this by providing distance in decimal according to your requirement.link is mention below for decimal points.

**LINK** : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Hibernate 5 supports Spatial.

You need to add the dependecy

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.17.Final</version><!-- In my case was this version, needs to match with your hibernate core version-->
</dependency>
```

Then you need to use the right dialect depending on your PostgreSQL version.

A list of them:

```
org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG9Dialect
org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG82Dialect
org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG91Dialect
org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG92Dialect
org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG93Dialect
org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG94Dialect
org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG95Dialect
```

After setting the correct dialect you can use Point or Polygon(there is no need to use @Type) in your entities. They come in the package *com.vividsolutions.jts.geom*

Creating a Point:

```
GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
Point point = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(lat, lon));
```

Comment: btw I did this using MySql.

Comment: This answer misses the point of the question: the user is trying to persist a `geography` and not a `geometry`. Geographies can be persisted using Hibernate Spatial, but one should set the SRID of the geometry to 4326 (WGS84).

Comment: Can anyone help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76952490/point-data-type-into-mysql8