# JPA @Query count AND select

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a somewhat complicated @Query in a JpaRepository.

I need to get the results of this query in two forms (but not at the same time!):

- First, the client asks for a count of the number of results: `SELECT COUNT(x.*) FROM my_table x ...`
- Then later (maybe), they want to see the actual data: `SELECT x.* FROM my_table x ...`

What follows (the `...`) is identical for both queries. Is there any way to combine these so that I don't repeat myself?

- I know I could just use the second method, and count the number of elements in the resulting List. However, this adds the overhead of actually fetching all those elements from the database.
- I could put the `...` in a String constant somewhere, but that kind of separates it from its context (I'd lose IntelliJ's syntax highlighting/error checking)
- I can't convert it to a Criteria or Example query, because I need to use PostGIS's **geography** type. (And these are less readable anyway...)

Any other ideas?

Comment: Using two separate queries already meets your requirements and seems like the only option here.

Comment: It also violates DRY...

Comment: If you aren't sure that you would even need to run the second query, then how can you justify running it ahead of schedule?

Comment: I don't run it ahead of time. I run the first query and report the count. Then later, if I get the request, I run the second query and return the results.

Comment: JPA really has nothing to do with this, it's just a database problem.  If you _don't_ run the full query at first, then you have to run it a second time.  Note here that time spent on the database isn't really the issue, it's the extra roundtrip you have to make to and from your application.

Comment: As regards the conversion to a Criteria query, Hibernate [does support PostGis spatial types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314732/use-postgis-geography-point-with-hibernate-spatial-5-in-spring-boot), and even [registers certain custom functions](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-spatial/src/main/java/org/hibernate/spatial/dialect/postgis/PostgisFunctions.java), so maybe that's a possibility after all

Comment: @crizzis Ah thanks for the link; I had searched but couldn't find anywhere that used Geography. I'll have to give it a try.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was hoping that JPA (or Spring, or Hibernate) might have some way of having a reusable SQL fragment, similar to a \@NamedQuery

Answer (score 0):

If your worries is about some developer change the `COUNT` query and forgot to change the `SELECT` query too, you can create a repository **integration test** to guarantee the expected result between the two queries.

Another alternative is create a **unit test** to read the annotation content and verify if the final of these two queries are equal.