# Point data type into MySQL8

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jts

I have a class with JTS point:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Check {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Point location;
```

I then want to save that point to my database

```
   Point location = new GeometryFactory().createPoint((new Coordinate(10, 10, 4326)));
   // Hibernate method to save entity
```

After doing some reading I can see people using a WKTReader to convert to some other format (WKB?) before storing it in the MySQL db.

When I try the stack trace says :

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1406, SQLState: 22001
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Data truncation: Data too long for column 'location' at row 1
```

**UPDATE**

Using dependency `org.geolatte.geom.*` works perfectly:

```
        Point<G2D> geolatte_location = point(WGS84,g(1744.33,-53.21));
```

Which makes me think I need to convert the point before I store it - how do I convert it so it will be able to be used in the constructor and resulting SQL?

Environment:
Java 18
Gradle
MySQL8
Hibernate 6.2
Spring Boot 3.2

The column in the table for the point created by hibernate is varbinary(255) - I thought MySQL8 supported Spatial point type.

Comment: can you please share your DDL for the table. The error says, the object size is bigger than the column size

Comment: The DDL is generated by Hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the test with Spring boot 3.1.2 and H2 database.

Add the hibernate spatial dependency in your project(version may vary).

`// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-spatial`
`implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:6.2.6.Final'`

Then you will see that the column definition of location is geometry. No transformation needed.

Hibernate spatial uses the locationtech library.

Comment: Thanks. I think the different is the MySQL8 vs H2.

Comment: I did another test but this time on mysql and it works. Can you post your application.properties and maven/gradle config?

Comment: Using org.springframework.data.geo.Point makes Hibernate create the Point as varbinary

Answer (score 1):

in my experience, you need to add the hibernate-spatial dependency, and also set the proper dialect, like in:

```yaml
    spring:
      jpa:
        ...
        properties:
          hibernate:
            ...
            dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG10Dialect
```

You can choose to use JTS or Geolatte geometries, both will work.